# Casting QString to char* unstable?

Tags: c++, qt, casting

Trying to identify why only less than 1% of the time I am having writing problems to memory.  As if from a random thread it is not able to write.  I am wondering if the casting is unstable?

```
char *str = (char*)q_str.toStdString().c_str();
memcpy(m_list + m_count + m_length, str, strlen(str));
m_count++;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toStdString()` returns a temporary. This temporary is destroyed at the semicolon, at which point `str` becomes a dangling pointer. Make it

```
string s = q_str.toStdString();
memcpy(m_list + m_count + m_length, s.c_str(), s.length());
```